# Show that $\sum_{r+s=k}a_rb_s=\sum_{r=0}^{k}a_rb_{k-r}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

$k\in\mathbb{N_0}$

The left sum says that I take every pair $(r,s)\in\mathbb{N_0}^2$ such that $r+s=k$.

I really don't know how I can argueto get the identity.

I have tried to argue with bijectivity. I would have a set like $\{(r,s)\in\mathbb{N_0}^2:r+s=k\}$ with induction I maybe could show that it is bijective to $\{0,....,k\}$. But I could only Show the inductionbase and not the inductionstep. And even if I would have succeeded I don't know how I could proceed.

I have got the hunch that it is sufficient to prove that

$$\{(r,s)\in\mathbb{N_0}^2:r+s=k\}=\{(0,k),(1,k-1),...,(k,0)\}$$

Therefore one could also make the inclusiontest. But I cannot justify this hunch. I.e. I don't know how I can argue that this would implicate the identity

$\sum_{r+s=k}a_rb_s=\sum_{r=0}^{k}a_rb_{k-r}$

This inclusion $\{(0,k),(1,k-1),...,(k,0)\}\subseteq \{(r,s)\in\mathbb{N_0} ^2:r+s=k\}$

is clear.

But not the other inclusion.

Can you help me to fill in the gaps please?

Comment: And what are those pairs? For a given $k$, they are precisely $(r,k-r)$ for each integer $r$ with $0\leq r \leq k$. That's just because $r+s=k$ if and only if $s=k-r$.

Comment: @MPW I will take an element of this set $x\in\{(r,s)\in\mathbb{N_0}^2:r+s=k\}=\{(0,k),(1,k-1),...,(k,0)\}$ Then $x=(r,s)$ and $r+s=k$. Because $r,s\in \mathbb{N_0}, r,s\geq 0$ And because $r+s=k, r,s\leq k$. I fix the $r$ then $s$ has to be $k-r$. Since $x$ was arbitrary all $x\in\{(r,s)\in\mathbb{N_0}^2:r+s=k\}=\{(0,k),(1,k-1),...,(k,0)\}$ are also element of $\{(r,s)\in\mathbb{N_0}^2:r+s=k\}=\{(0,k),(1,k-1),...,(k,0)\}$. Therefore the sets are equal and because of commutativity the Arrangement of the pairs is not inportant and therefor the identity which is one Arrangement/Permutation holds

Comment: If there is something wrong please tell me

Comment: $x\in\{(r,s)\in\mathbb{N_0}^2:r+s=k\}$

Answer (score 1):

Following your idea, fix $k\in \mathbb N$ and note that if

$W=\{(r,s):r+s=k\}$ and $T=\{(r,k-r):0\le r\le k\},$ then

$ w\in W\Leftrightarrow w=(r,s)\  \text{and}\  r+s=k\Leftrightarrow$

$  w=(r,k-r)\  \text{and}\  r=k-s\Leftrightarrow w=(r,k-r)\ \text{and}\ 0\le r\le k \Leftrightarrow w\in T.$

Comment: Okey wait $w=(r,s)$ and $r+s=k$ then $r=k-s$ and $s=k-r$ then we can rewrite $(r,s)$ to $(r,k-r)$ but why is then $1\leq r\leq k$?

Comment: It's another typo, I am typing into my phone on the subway. : $k$ is $fixed$ so since $r+s=k,\ r$ ranges from $0$ to $k$, right? All I did was follow your idea, which is correct. The pairs match up bijectively because you are just rearranging them. In fact, you can draw a 2-d  picture to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: I don't like contradiction Proofs because I can never remember them but I see no other way in this case if we assume $r>k$ we would get a contradiction that $s\in\mathbb{N_0}$. We have proved now that $w\in T$. The only Thing that I have to understand is that $T=\{(r,k-r):0\le r\le k\}=\{(0,k),(1,k-1),...,(k,0)\}$